# How to move a Todo element at the end of the list and bring it back to the same position when undone in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React for only a few days now. I'm making a Todo app and I would like to add the following feature: when I mark a task as `done`, it should move to bottom. If I make the same task as `undone` then it should maintain its original position.

My code starting from the App structure:

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header';
import List from './components/List';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="Todo App">
      <Headers />
      <Form />
      <ListItems />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
const Header = () => {
    return (
        <h1>My Todo App</h1>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display two lists, one not done and one done, one after another

```
{todos.filter(todo => !todo.isDone).map((todo, index) => (
  <Item
    key={index}
    index={index}
    todo={todo}
    markTodo={markTodo}
    removeTodo={removeTodo}
  />
))}
{todos.filter(todo => todo.isDone).map((todo, index) => (
  <Item
    key={index}
    index={index}
    todo={todo}
    markTodo={markTodo}
    removeTodo={removeTodo}
  />
))}
```

P.S.

`<li>` is list item, not list, you should use `<ul>` and each item should be `<li>`

P.S. 2

`index` isn't a good `key`

Comment: Thank you @Konrad! Also for the PSs, I'm actually facing an issue now when checking a todo item, and it must be related to the index thingy. Thanks again

Comment: I'm a bit desperate for help, could you please take a look with your senior eyes in case you can figure out why the tests are not passing? Thank you

Comment: P.S As per your suggestion I made each todo item have a key, so I'm not using the index. But is that maybe the issue? The first element in the array remains first even after the isDone becomes true after we toggle it as done. Maybe that's the reason? But then, I thought i shouldn't use indexes here.